# Google Maps Distance Matrix API duration in traffic adding all segments returning wrong result

Tags: google-api, distance, distance-matrix

I have sets of 11 points in a row along a road on Google maps
When I calculate the time required to travel between adjacent points and add them together the total result is not the same as time required to travel between first point and last point

i.e

```
A -> B
B -> C
C -> D

is not equal to 

A -> D
```

Can anyone example why this is the case.

Comment: Could you please provide some concrete examples? Perhaps a list of locations and their travel time, so that the behaviour is reproducible.

Comment: added the section in answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example:
I have some coordinates

```
`
p1=(49.338202, -123.142030)
p2=(49.335271, -123.125171)
p3=(49.332503, -123.116240)
p4=(49.332447, -123.104249)
p5=(49.331949, -123.092218)
p6=(49.331996, -123.077877)
p7=(49.329556, -123.054275)
p8=(49.326069, -123.048102)
p9=(49.312711, -123.030485)
p10=(49.306328, -123.028022)
p11=(49.291653, -123.026348)



directions_results1 = gmaps.distance_matrix(p1,p2,mode="driving",units="metric",departure_time=now,traffic_model= "best_guess")
directions_results2 = gmaps.distance_matrix(p2,p3,mode="driving",units="metric",departure_time=now,traffic_model= "best_guess")
directions_results3 = gmaps.distance_matrix(p3,p4,mode="driving",units="metric",departure_time=now,traffic_model= "best_guess")
directions_results4 = gmaps.distance_matrix(p4,p5,mode="driving",units="metric",departure_time=now,traffic_model= "best_guess")
directions_results5 = gmaps.distance_matrix(p5,p6,mode="driving",units="metric",departure_time=now,traffic_model= "best_guess")
directions_results6 = gmaps.distance_matrix(p6,p7,mode="driving",units="metric",departure_time=now,traffic_model= "best_guess")
directions_results7 = gmaps.distance_matrix(p7,p8,mode="driving",units="metric",departure_time=now,traffic_model= "best_guess")
directions_results8 = gmaps.distance_matrix(p8,p9,mode="driving",units="metric",departure_time=now,traffic_model= "best_guess")
directions_results9 = gmaps.distance_matrix(p9,p10,mode="driving",units="metric",departure_time=now,traffic_model= "best_guess")
directions_results10 = gmaps.distance_matrix(p10,p11,mode="driving",units="metric",departure_time=now,traffic_model= "best_guess")

directions_resultst = gmaps.distance_matrix(p1,p11,mode="driving",units="metric",departure_time=now,traffic_model= "best_guess")



the number is in second

Output
Segment 1 Time: 149
Segment 2 Time: 37
Segment 3 Time: 63
Segment 4 Time: 49
Segment 5 Time: 49
Segment 6 Time: 96
Segment 7 Time: 35
Segment 8 Time: 141
Segment 9 Time: 134
Segment 10 Time: 134
Sum of Time required for all Segments: 887
Time required from First point to Last point: 1084
`
```